# Is this the way of truncating the fractional part of a BigDecimal when its scale is zero in Java?

Tags: java

I need to remove the fractional part of a `BigDecimal` value when its scale has a value of zero. For example,

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.00").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

It would assign `12.00`. I want it to assign only `12` to `value` in such cases.

---

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.000000").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

should assign `12`,

---

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.0001").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

should assign `12`.

---

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.0051").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

should assign`12.01`

---

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.99").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

should assign `12.99`.

---

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.999").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

should assign`13`

---

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.3456").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

should assign `12.35` and alike.

---

I have this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15590624/1391249).

For this to be so, I'm doing the following.

```
String text="123.008";
BigDecimal bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(text);

if(bigDecimal.scale()>2)
{
    bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(text).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
}

if(bigDecimal.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)==0)
{
    bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(text).setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
}

System.out.println("bigDecimal = "+bigDecimal);
```

It's just as an example. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Besides the content, a +1 for providing the tests. Makes it much easier to get an understanding of the desired functionality

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this?

Yes, `stripTrailingZeros()`.

To check your tests:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    check(truncate("12.000000"), "12");
    check(truncate("12.0001"), "12");
    check(truncate("12.0051"), "12.01");
    check(truncate("12.99"), "12.99");
    check(truncate("12.999"), "13");
    check(truncate("12.3456"), "12.35");
    System.out.println("if we see this message without exceptions, everything is ok");
}

private static BigDecimal truncate(final String text) {
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(text);
    if (bigDecimal.scale() > 2)
        bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(text).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
}

private static void check(final BigDecimal bigDecimal, final String string) {
    if (!bigDecimal.toString().equals(string))
        throw new IllegalStateException("not equal: " + bigDecimal + " and " + string);

}
```

output:

> if we see this message without exceptions, everything is ok

Comment: Good to know a precise, concise and recommended way. Thank you.

Comment: Be careful with this. `10.00` becomes `1E+1`, not `10`.

Comment: @stickfigure and how do I make it `10.00` and not `1E+1` ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do? I wanted prettier USD amounts, so I ended up manipulating the toString version (ie `cost.endsWith(".00") ? cost.substring(0, cost.length() - 3) : cost`).

Comment: The proposed solutions passes the given tests. For the new case of `10.00`: The result is technically correct, only the printing may be inconvenient. The printing can be changed with `DecimalFormat`. Depending on the specification, `new DecimalFormat("0.00")` may be suitable.

Answer (score -1):

If you want just truncate (kotlin style)
val truncatedValue = BigDecimal("12.001").toBigInteger().toBigDecimal()

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually review the code, and it has different behaviour (it will truncate when the fractional part isn't zero, too).